# Passing a parameter into an MDX Query using Power Query in Excel

Tags: excel, powerquery, mdx, azure-analysis-services

I am using a parameter to build an MDX query to analysis services in a SQL Server Cube/Tabular Model. This is an example

```
AnalysisServices.Database("server_name", db_param, [Query = "SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE db = 'db_name'])
```

My parameter is 'db_param', and it works fine to build the connection to the right database inside the server, but I can't manage to pass it to the MDX query. I would essentially like to replace 'db_name' with db_param such that it calls the parameter.

Any ideas? I tried single brackets, double brackets, inside quotation marks, not inside quotation marks. And I can't seem to create a chain either. (e.g. "SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE db = " + db_param + "rest of the query"]

Any ideas?

Comment: In general, you need to use & not + to combine. let aa = "ddd", bb= "ccc", statement = "SELECT * FROM  "&aa& " WHERE db='"&bb&"'", Source =[Query = statement]

Comment: Thank you, that worked. You indeed need to place the variable in "&var_here&" for it to work. I also noticed that in a where statement you still need to wrap the whole thing in ''. So for example "... WHERE constraint = '"&var_here&"' "
If you write your comment in an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you need to use & not + to combine.

```
let aa = "ddd", 
bb= "ccc", 
statement = "SELECT * FROM "&aa& " WHERE db='"&bb&"'", 
Source =[Query = statement]
in Source
```